# Why is the definition $\text{Work}= \text{Force}\cdot\text{Displacement}$ useful to describe the physical world?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, work, displacement

Why is the definition $\text{Work}= \text{Force}\cdot\text{Displacement}$ useful to describe the physical world?

Edit: Added another question as suggested by probably_someone, I think that this topic must also be covered to fully understand work

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526337/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does work equal force times distance?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/26797/)

Comment: Note that you do not derive definitions experimentally. They are just defined

Comment: I think there's a more interesting possibly-non-duplicate question that underpins this one: _What makes this definition of work useful for describing nature?_ If that's the question you're asking, feel free to make that clear.